# Add rows to data frame based on count

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| Species_ID | Location_ID | Altitude | Female | Male |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mon | WH | 1700 | 3 | 10 |
| jon | IF | 1850 | 5 | 2 |
| sylv | WS | 2100 | 7 | 3 |
| ter | MB | 1700 | 20 | 15 |

1. I would like to have a total number of individuals (Female & Male) as an extra column
2. I would like to add rows to the data frame based on the total number of individuals, each row containing all info of the columns. So for example for the Species_ID "mon" we have a total number of 13 individuals. So i want 13 extra rows containing all infos of "Species_ID", "Location_ID" and "Altitude"

I pretty sure I can handle the first question by using mutate(), but I have absolutely no idea how to solve the second step.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags only, i.e. don't tag-spam irrelevant tags like [tag:edit].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uncount` from `tidyr`. The optional argument `.id` creates a new variable which gives a unique identifier for each created row.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  uncount(Female + Male, .id = "ID")

#    Species_ID Location_ID Altitude Female Male ID
# 1         mon          WH     1700      3   10  1
# 2         mon          WH     1700      3   10  2
# 3         mon          WH     1700      3   10  3
# 4         mon          WH     1700      3   10  4
# 5         mon          WH     1700      3   10  5
# 6         mon          WH     1700      3   10  6
# 7         mon          WH     1700      3   10  7
# 8         mon          WH     1700      3   10  8
# 9         mon          WH     1700      3   10  9
# 10        mon          WH     1700      3   10 10
# 11        mon          WH     1700      3   10 11
# 12        mon          WH     1700      3   10 12
# 13        mon          WH     1700      3   10 13
# ...
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(
  list(Species_ID = c("mon", "jon", "sylv", "ter"),
       Location_ID = c("WH", "IF", "WS", "MB"),
       Altitude = c(1700L, 1850L, 2100L, 1700L), 
       Female = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 20L),
       Male = c(10L, 2L, 3L, 15L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)
d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Species_ID,  ~Location_ID,   ~Altitude,  ~Female,    ~Male, 
"mon",  "WH",   1700,   3,  10,
"jon",  "IF",   1850,   5,  2,
"sylv", "WS",   2100,   7,  3,
"ter",  "MB",   1700,   20, 15)


d <- d %>% 
  mutate(all_obs = Female + Male)

d[rep(1:nrow(d), d$all_obs), 1:3]
#> # A tibble: 65 × 3
#>    Species_ID Location_ID Altitude
#>    <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 mon        WH              1700
#>  2 mon        WH              1700
#>  3 mon        WH              1700
#>  4 mon        WH              1700
#>  5 mon        WH              1700
#>  6 mon        WH              1700
#>  7 mon        WH              1700
#>  8 mon        WH              1700
#>  9 mon        WH              1700
#> 10 mon        WH              1700
#> # … with 55 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot so far. The 360 rows of my dataframe are now almost 1700 rows in the tibble of my data (didn't know this function before). But how can I get it as a data frame I can use for analysis?
Because if I use "as.data.frame()", I get the exact data frame before I used this command "d[rep(1:nrow(d), d$all_obs), 1:3]", which has again 360 rows, but the sums of my desired columns..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved it like this:

```
b2 <- b1 %>% 
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(all_obs = sum(Weibchen,Arbeiterinnen,Männchen, na.rm=TRUE))
 %>% 
dplyr::select(Taxon_ID, Standort, Höhenstufe, all_obs)

b3 <- uncount(b2, all_obs, .remove=TRUE, .id="ID")
```

Comment: Only problem left: Several rows have same ID values, for example there are several rows with ID 1, 3 or 5

Comment: If you don't want the ID, just remove `.id="ID"` in `uncount`.

Comment: Obviously you have adopted the solution in my post. You could accept my answer by clicking the check mark instead of posting a new one.

Comment: You should mark provided solution as the answer. Instead of creating new answer.

Comment: Alright, I marked the answer. Thanks a lot for helping!
Just concerning the ID: yes, of course, if i dont want the ID i can just remove it. But if i have 1700 rows, shouldn't the ID begin at 1 and end at 1700? Instead it allocates (seemingly) random numbers to the rows, i don't understand why

Comment: It's not random numbers. The optional argument `.id` creates a new variable which gives a unique identifier for each created row. You can use a smaller toy dataset to see how it works. Try `df <- data.frame(x = c('A', 'B', 'C'), y = 2:4); tidyr::uncount(df, y, .id = "seq")`

Comment: If you want a extra column indicating the row numbers, you can create it bt `mutate(id = 1:n())`, or `mutate(id = row_number())`